# Django CRUD Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-forms, django-views

I am building an application where I want users to be able to create posts. However, when I added the functionalities nothing happens after creating the 'Post' button, I can see that Django is not getting the url in the console.

Here is my Ajax code for Creating, Updating and Removing, the Update and remove work fine however the create is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ShowForm = function(){
        var btn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: btn.attr("data-url"),
            type: 'get',
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#modal-post').modal('show');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#modal-post .modal-content').html(data.html_form);
            }
        });
    };

    var SaveForm =  function(){
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('data-url'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.form_is_valid){
                    $('#post-list div').html(data.posts);
                    $('#modal-post').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    $('#modal-post .modal-content').html(data.html_form)
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    }

// create 
$(".show-form-create").click(ShowForm);
$("#modal-post").on("submit",".create-form",SaveForm);

//update
$('#post-list').on("click",".show-form-update",ShowForm);
$('#modal-post').on("submit",".update-form",SaveForm)

//delete
$('#post-list').on("click",".show-form-delete",ShowForm);
$('#modal-post').on("submit",".delete-form",SaveForm)
});
```

This is my views.py:

```
@login_required
def save_all(request,form,template_name):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():      
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            posts = Post.objects.all()
            data['posts'] = render_to_string('home/home_post.html',{'posts':posts})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {
    'form':form
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name,context,request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data) 

@login_required
def post_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return save_all(request, form, 'home/post_create.html')
```

And this is the button I use:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary show-form-create ml-auto" data-url="{% url 'home:post-create' %}">Post</button>
```

When I change the **show-form-create** to **show-form-delete** the PostForm pops up however when I change it back it seems not to be working. I have been on this issue for a while I cannot find what is causing the issue.

This is also available in my urls.py:

```
path('post/create/', views.post_create, name='post-create'),
```

I appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There are no errors it simply does not do anything. When I click on 'Post' nothing happens, nothing even shows on the console - @riNg